# Is there a fix for Windows 8 Release Preview freezing intermittently on Macbook Air

Tags: windows-8-preview, boot-camp

I've successfully installed Windows 8 x64 Release Preview on a 2010 Macbook Air (4GB/256GB).  I was also able to install the Apple Boot Camp tools without incident, but the computer will intermittently freeze up completely (need a forced shutdown) for no apparent reason.  As such, there is no logging information to help me troubleshoot this any further.

I have no other software installed at this point; only the latest updates from Microsoft.  Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing you need to remember, above and in front of everything else... is that this is a BETA release.  Windows 8 Consumer Preview is not a *Release Candidate*.  It is not a final product.  It is a PREVIEW.  There are going to be issues and bugs.  So, what you need to do is *not* expect it to function perfectly.  That means you can't expect there to be fixes and patches... the OS hasn't even been released officially yet.  So, you should be directing your experiences directly to Microsoft, to allow them to work with your findings.

Comment: @BonGart - He installed the Release Preview not Customer Preview.  The Release Preview is a `Release Candidate`.  The Customer Preview and Developer Preview were a `Beta` builds.

Comment: @Ramhound.  Brilliant.  It **IS** a release candidate?  Wow.  I wonder if Microsoft knows that.  Guess I'll just have to provide an actual answer to deal with this latest development.

Comment: @Bon Gart, Ramhound: Guess what? [The RTM is also affected.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61155/windows-8-rtm-freezes-on-mac-book-pro)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this freezing problem by installing Hyper-V as suggested in the below URL.

[Broken No More? A Windows 8 Release Preview Freeze Workaround](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/broken-windows-8-release-preview-freeze-workaround-143550)

The installation is explained here:

[Windows 8 Feature Focus: Client Hyper-V](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-client-hyperv-142889)

And as suggested in the article, I have an SSD and my computer with Windows 8 Release Preview froze several times per day before installing Hyper-V. Since installing Hyper-v yesterday, there has not been a single freeze.

Answer (score 2):

There's a well documented freezing issue under the RP, which a lot of tech bloggers like Paul Thurrott and Raphael Rivera have been experiencing. A solution is provided here and it is apparently already fixed for the RTM release: http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/broken-windows-8-release-preview-freeze-workaround-143550

Answer (score 2):

What solved that problem in my case was updating graphics drivers of the HD-3000 with beta drivers from Intel website.

Neither the drivers in Windows 8 nor Boot Camp worked.

In your case (MacBook Air 2010) I suggest to update the NVIDIA driver. It could do the trick. 
Note that I also had bad performance with WiFi. Updating the broadcom drivers solved that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the workaround direct from Microsoft that disables the Dynamic Ticks feature.

You can do this with the command `bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes` from an elevated command line according to the [within windows blog](http://www.withinwindows.com/2012/06/28/workaround-for-windows-8-freezing-issues/)